# How can I handle DLL errors in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, error-handling, memory-access

The API declaration:

```
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" ( _
                         ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, _
                         ByVal HWnd As Long, _
                         ByVal msg As Long, _
                         ByVal wParam As Long, _
                         ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

will crash Excel when provided with a non-existent function pointer for the `lpPrevWndFunc` parameter.

Similarly,

```
Private Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByRef Destination As LongPtr, _
                                                  ByRef Source As LongPtr, _
                                                  ByVal Length As Long)
```

isn't happy when `Destination` or `Source` don't exist.

I think these errors are memory access violations. I assume Windows tells the caller that it's doing something it can't<sup>1</sup> - perhaps it sends a message to Excel and there's no handler for it? MSDN has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) to say about it:

> System errors during calls to Windows dynamic-link libraries (DLL) or
>   Macintosh code resources do not raise exceptions and cannot be trapped
>   with Visual Basic error trapping. **When calling DLL functions, you
>   should check each return value for success or failure** (according to
>   the API specifications), and in the event of a failure, check the
>   value in the Err object's LastDLLError property. LastDLLError always
>   returns zero on the Macintosh.
>   *(emphasis my own)*

But in these instances I have no values to check for errors, I just get a crash.

<sub>1: Provided it catches the error which it might not always, if say a memory rewrite is valid but undefined. But certainly writing to restricted memory or calling fake pointers should be caught before they're executed right?</sub>

#### I'm most interested in:

1. What causes this crash (both *how it is triggered*, and *what exactly the mechanism is behind it* - how does Excel know it needs to be crashing?). What is the message channel over which these errors are being communicated, and can I intercept them with VBA code?
2. Whether the crash can be pro-actively (i.e. sanitising inputs etc.) or retro-actively (handling errors) prevented.

I think (1) will likely shed light on (2) and vice-versa

---

Anyway, if anyone knows how to handle API errors like these without Excel crashing, or how to avoid them happening, or anything that would be fab. `On Error Resume Next` doesn't seem to work...

```
Sub CrashExcel()
    On Error Resume Next 'Lord preserve us
    'Copy 300 bytes from one non existent memory pointer to another
    RtlMoveMemory ByVal 100, ByVal 200, 300 
    On Error Goto 0
    Debug.Assert Err.LastDllError = 0 'Yay no errors
End Sub
```

#### Motivation

There are 2 main reasons I'm asking about this:

1. Developing code (the process of debugging etc.) is made much harder when Excel crashes every time I make a mistake. This is not something that can be solved by simply *getting it right myself* (and exposing a different interface to client code, which uses my existing correct implementations of API calls) because I rarely get it right first time!
2. I would like to create robust code which is able to handle errors in user input (e.g. invalid function pointers or memory write locations). This can be dealt with to an extent by, for example, abstracting function pointers away into callable classes, but that's not a general solution for other kinds of dll errors (and still doesn't deal with 1.)

---

Specifically, I'm trying to develop a friendly interface to wrap [WinAPI timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer). These require callback functions to be registered with them, which (given the limitations of VBA) have to come in the form of `Long` function pointers (generated with the `AddressOf` keyword).

The callbacks come from user code and may be invalid. The whole point of my wrapping is to improve stability of the API calls, and this is one area that needs improvement.

The memory copy problem is probably out of scope of this question, it's to do with making generators in VBA, but I think the same error handling techniques would be applicable there too, and it makes for an easier example.

I also get errors and crashes from the Timer API generating too many unhandled messages for Excel. Once again I wonder, how does Windows tell Excel "Time to crash now", why can't I intercept that instruction and deal with the error myself (i.e. Kill all the Timers I made & flush the message queue)?

Comment: `how to avoid them happening`: the only real way to avoid this is to pass valid pointers.  An access violation is not the same thing as a System Error returned by a Win32API call.

Comment: Exactly. Your problem is not that you need to work out how to deal with the errors after they have happened. You need to fix the defects in your code that led to the errors in the first place. Once you fix the defects, the errors don't occur.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see the point you're trying to make, however I think you've misunderstood the use case (perhaps I didn't explain it clearly). The function pointer I get comes from client code/ it is a variable I have no control over. It is typed as a `Long` so could be any number. Therefore I'd like some way to check whether the pointer is valid/ handle the case where it isn't. Similarly with memory copying - I get passed a source/destination pointer - this comes from external code I have no control over. It needs to be sanitised in some way.

Comment: @Joe Would you mind expanding a little on what makes the errors different? Presumably they come from different sources - but other than that my understanding  is too limited to really understand. As far as I am aware the errors can be communicated to Excel either through return values of the API call (_'System Errors'_?), or Windows messages sent to the process (everything else?). But that's a very beginner understanding and I'm not confident, and would love some more info if possible!

Comment: I have not misunderstood. The problem is that your expectations are not viable. You can't check whether or not an arbitrary address can safely be passed as `lpPrevWndFunc`. You have to demand that whoever provides the function pointer, does so correctly. Likewise, you cannot expect to receive an arbitrary address and overwrite the memory at that address. Once again the onus is on whoever supplies the pointer, to ensure that it is valid.

Comment: @Greedo the short answer is, there is no reliable way to sanitize a raw pointer. An access violation is reported via a [Structured Exception (SEH)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/structured-exception-handling) (see [How to use structured exception handling in Visual Basic .NET or in Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315965/how-to-use-structured-exception-handling-in-visual-basic-net-or-in-vis)), however VBA does not directly support SEH, IIRC. Why are you allowing external code to send you raw pointers to begin with? What is the use case here?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Currently I'm designing code to attach user supplied callback functions to the [WinApi Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), while exposing a friendly interface, and keeping track of everything behind the scenes. Yes I never actually thought it would be possible to sanitise the raw pointers - I was more envisaging a python style, try and use, deal with the consequences later (EAFP?) approach:) But it's the dealing with consequences that I'm finding tricky. Updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: This is how Win32 programming works. You expect clients of your API to follow the rules. If they don't, it's their fault when bad things happen. Just make the rules clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Frankly, that could be most of an answer. Although I'm still not entirely convinced I understand why *'when bad things happen'* there's nothing my code can do about it? Surely if I make an erroneous API call, something's gotta let Excel/my code know that it was bad, and then Excel crashes on an unhandled exception (possibly observable/handle-able). Or maybe the crashing mechanism is different (e.g Excel hangs waiting for a return from the API that never comes, and then Windows kills the process as it's unresponsive- much harder to observe/catch I think). I really don't know.

Comment: Some very interesting discussion so I hope an answer comes out of this.

Comment: @Greedo "*Currently I'm designing code to attach user supplied callback functions to the WinApi Timer*" - Please show your actual code for that. I would not suggest assigning the user's callback DIRECTLY to the timer. Assign YOUR OWN callback to the timer, and then have YOUR callback call the USER'S callback.

Comment: @Greedo "*Surely if I make an erroneous API call, something's gotta let Excel/my code know that it was bad*" - says who? If something unexpected happens, like accessing invalid memory, it is random undefined behavior, and literally ANYTHING can happen. For well-defined errors (bad parameters, etc), the API may just return an error code. But for unknown errors (bad memory, etc), the OS *MAY* catch the error and issue an appropriate SEH exception up the call stack until SOMEONE handles it, and that someone is likely not going to be VBA with its very limited error handling capabilities.

Answer (score 10):

From a comment:

> Surely if I make an erroneous API call, something's gotta let Excel/my code know that it was bad

Not necessarily.  If you ask an API function (e.g. `RtlMoveMemory`) to overwrite memory at a location for which you supply a pointer, it will cheerfully attempt to do so.  Then a number of things could happen:

- If the memory is not writable (e.g. code), then you will be lucky enough to get an access violation which will terminate the process before it can do any more damage.
- If the memory happens writable, it will be overwritten and thus corrupted, after which all bets are off.

From your comment:

> I'm designing code to attach user supplied callback functions

An alternative would be to design an interface with methods that your client code can implement. Then require the client to pass an instance of a class that implements that interface.

If your clients are VBA, then an easy way to define an interface is to create a public VBA class module with one or more empty methods.  By convention, you should name this class with an `I` (for interface) prefix - e.g. `IMyCallback`.  The empty method(s) (Subs or Functions) can have any signature you want, but I'll keep it simple:

Example:

```
Class module name: IMyCallback

Option Explicit

Public Sub MyMethod()

End Sub
```

Alternatively, and better if your clients use languages other than VBA, you can use IDL to define the interface, compile it into a type library, and reference the type library from your VBA project.  I won't go into that any further here but ask another question if you want to follow it up.

Then your clients should create a class (VBA class module) that implements this interface in whatever way they choose, e.g. by creating a class module `ClientCallback`:

```
Class module name: ClientCallback

Option Explicit

Implements IMyCallback

Private Sub IMyCallback_MyMethod()
    ' Client adds his implementation here
End Sub
```

You then expose an argument of type `IMyCallback` and your client can pass an instance of his class.

Your method:

```
Public Sub RegisterCallback(Callback as IMyCallback)
    ...
End Sub
```

Client code:

```
Dim objCallback as New ClientCallback
RegisterCallback Callback
…
```

You can then implement your own callback function that is called from a Timer, and safely call the client code via the interface.

Comment: Just to clarify why I posted a bounty rather than accepting this answer: Whilst this does provide a good workaround (I mean that, I +1d too, and it's definitely going to be the next step), it only provides a solution to a specific aspect of my problem, and skirts around the aspect I'm most interested in (fair enough considering I only clarified the scope when I set the bounty, _after_ this answer was posted). But as I say, this doesn't address the development aspect of working with APIs which is probably my greatest concern with the way things work now, nor does it apply to other DLL errors.

Answer (score 4):

Some of these Windows API calls can be dangerous.  If you want to ship Windows API functionality as a library feature then it would be courteous not to expose you clients to such danger.  So, you are best to implement your own interface layer.

Below is code that ships the Windows Timer API as a library feature that is safe for use because it passes string names of callback code instead of pointers.

This code was [first published on my blog](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2019/05/vba-make-windows-timer-as-library.html).  Also on that blog post I discuss alternatives to Application.Run if you want options.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'* Brought to you by the Excel Development Platform blog
'* First published at https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2019/05/vba-make-windows-timer-as-library.html

Private Declare Function ApiSetTimer Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetTimer" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
                        ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ApiKillTimer Lib "user32.dll" Alias "KillTimer" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Private mdicCallbacks As New Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub SetTimer(ByVal sUserCallback As String, lMilliseconds As Long)
    Dim retval As Long  ' return value

    Dim lUniqueId As Long
    lUniqueId = mdicCallbacks.HashVal(sUserCallback) 'should be unique enough

    mdicCallbacks.Add lUniqueId, sUserCallback

    retval = ApiSetTimer(Application.hWnd, lUniqueId, lMilliseconds, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Private Sub TimerProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, _
        ByVal dwTime As Long)

    ApiKillTimer Application.hWnd, idEvent

    Dim sUserCallback As String
    sUserCallback = mdicCallbacks.Item(idEvent)
    mdicCallbacks.Remove idEvent


    Application.Run sUserCallback
End Sub

'****************************************************************************************************************************************
' User code below
'****************************************************************************************************************************************

Private Sub TestSetTimer()
    SetTimer "UserCallBack", 500
End Sub

Private Function UserCallBack()
    Debug.Print "hello from UserCallBack"
End Function
```